# Grab contacts from list view with CheckBoxes

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-contacts, listadapter

I've created a List view composed of two text views and a checkbox, and contacts are printing. However, I am unable to use the checkboxes to return them back to my program and add them to my Person class.

```
public void populateListView(View view) {
    try {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            list.add(new Person(name, phoneNumber));
        }
        phones.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new myListAdapter();
    ListView listview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlistview);
    listview2.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

    public myListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.da_item, list);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.da_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Find person wot work with
        Person currentperson = list.get(position);

        // Fill the view
        TextView nameboxview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.NameView);
        nameboxview.setText(currentperson.getName());

        TextView numberboxview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.NumberView);
        numberboxview.setText(currentperson.getPhone());



        return itemView;
    }
}

public void registerDoneClick(View view) {
    View itemView = view;
    ListView lister = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlistview);
    long[] id = lister.getCheckedItemIds();
    TextView nameboxview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.NameView);
    TextView numberboxview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.NumberView);

    for(int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
        Person human = new Person(nameboxview.toString(), numberboxview.toString());
        persons.add(human);
        BetterDisplay(human);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void grabthecontacts(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.selectcontacts);
    populateListView(view);
}
```

I found an older thread about something very similar to what Im doing but it he seemed to have used a different method to post the results so I was completely confused as it looked entirely different than what I wrote.
Im new to Java and Android development in general. I think Im probably completely off in regards to returning the values and formatting, any help will be appreciated.